# How to set up .htaccess rules for visits from outside the domain only?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can't seem to find any way to do this:

I have ah .htaccess redirect set up on my site to take visitors from my homepage site.com to a landing page on welcome.site.com.

```
RewriteRule ^(index.html)?$ http://welcome.example.com [R,L]
```

However, the problem is that we also have users accesing and using the site thought a site.com/login url and now any time they click home on the navigation menu or any other links in there, they are taken to the landing page instead of the proper site.com page. Is there any way to set up the .htaccess in such a way so as to exclude any visits coming from inside the domain from this redirect?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` parameter and see if it contains your domain name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index.html)?$ http://welcome.example.com [R,L]
```

Comment: Tried this but it did not work, still redirecting to the landing page. A link from http://www.example.com/anything.php still takes me to the welcome.example.com page.

Comment: I also noticed you removed the parentheses and ? from ^index in the rule and doing that actually caused it not redirect to the landing page at all.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was sloppy. I modified this a bit so that it also works when not using www, does this work better for you?

Comment: Thank Stephan, but still no luck. What would be a simple redirect to move all domain.com links to domain.com/index.php, but while keeping the original redirect to welcome intact? Im thinking that may work...

Comment: Found a solution finally! Here's the way to check referrer that worked in case anyone has this problem:   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*